# Python - Issue handling list of ip addresses as string list when single ip element

Tags: python, string, list, ip

I try to manage a list of ip addresses as strings, and print them like:

```
iplist = ("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2",...)
for ip in iplist:
  print ip
```

resulting in:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
....
```

If the list has more than one element, it works, but if the list has a single element, it use the single ip like a string character list and print:

```
1
9
2
. 
1
....
```

How can I handle this issue in a simple manner?

Comment: That won't happen unless you define `iplist` as the actual string. It's not a list currently anyway, it's a tuple, but if you define a list and append IPs to it, you won't have this issue because the container itself is iterable.

Comment: I think your problem is upstream of the code you've posted. `iplist = ("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2",...)` is presumably the result of some other code, which returns a raw string in the case of a single result. We can't see the code that generates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have isn't a list of IP addresses, but a tuple.

In the case of a singleton tuple, adding a comma fixes your problem.

```
iplist = ("192.168.1.1",)
for ip in iplist:
    print ip
```

Converting it to a list also fixes the problem.

```
iplist = ["192.168.1.1"]
for ip in iplist:
    print ip
```

The important difference between a list and tuple is that lists can be appended to, while tuples are immutable.

It's generally best to use lists for data that can be added to (like a list of IP addresses), and to reserve tuples for structured data (like x-y coordinates).

Comment: This is true, but I'm curious about how the OP ended up with a tuple that simply becomes parentheses in the case of a single item :)

Comment: I think Python correctly interprets a string in parentheses as a string. Adding a trailing comma seems necessary in the case of a singleton tuple.

Comment: Exactly, so what code is there that creates a valid tuple in the case of multiple results but just gives the raw string in the case of a single result?

Comment: I get your meaning! I'm curious as well.